# How to store and query object in redis using properties on the object

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to store an object in Redis using the `StackExchangeRedisCacheClient` i am looking to store an item which contains the following

Id
Price
Title
UserId
Category

I need to be able to find items by either Id, category or UserId.

I am currently adding these properties to the key and searching for the key. I am concerned with possible performance degradation. Is this the best way to achieve what i need ?

Comment: Do need to find item by Id OR category OR userId (or a combination of 2 of 3 etc), or do you always know Id, category and userId?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear i need to find by one property so OR

Comment: Giving an exact answer is difficult without knowing volumes, datatypes etc but a possible approach is to store a `Hash` of the main item object and have multiple `Sets` (or `SortedSets`) to index the `Hash` Key by different fields then use `SINTER` or `SUNION` commands to find the appropriate `Hash` key.

Comment: OK thanks can c# objects be used as hashes

Comment: Yes but you can't search through fields of a hash which is why I mentioned Sets and SortedSets. You can store the properties in the key like you are now but you'll still have the same perf issues.